# How can I get the raster cell values for a set of rasters in PostGIS, for each cell that intersects an arbitrary, user-provided polygon?

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

In PostGIS, I have a set of (large, U.S.-wide) rasters at high (30m) resolution. For my application, I need to take an arbitrary area of interest provided by the user, likely ranging in size from dozens to hundreds of raster cells, and then get back out a table containing the values for each cell, in each raster. What I'm ultimately looking for is essentially a normalized table, something like this:

| cell_id | raster_id | raster_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 284 | 30 | .2546 |

I don't *necessarily* need each cell to have a unique identifier, but it's important that I know, for example, that the value for raster 1 in a given cell was 0.152, and the value for raster 2 in *that same cell* was 9.3. I'll ultimately be doing some math to multiply each of those raster values by a user-defined factor, with each of those raster values for a given cell, to get a resulting value for each cell (which could be just tabular info).

I know I can use ST_Value or ST_PixelAsPoint to get the value for a particular pixel, given point input, and I've seen examples for getting *summary stats* for raster values within a polygon, but no examples that will give back a table or list of values for each raster, for all cells intersecting a polygon, on a cell by cell basis.

Comment: Which is your table schema? Are all raster aligned and have the same size? Are your asking for postgis only solutions? If yes remove the rasterio tag.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga, all rasters are aligned and have the same extent/cell size, etc. At this point, all are rasters, so I don't have a specific table schema, but I would like the results to have an output format as shown in the table.